# ag-grid: services are found undefined in custom cell renderer after horizontally scrolling backward and forward

Tags: angular, ag-grid, angular-services, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid in my agular project. I'm using custom cell renderer defined in framwework component like

```
    public frameworkComponents = {
    statusrenderer: StatusRendererComponent,
    columnheaderrenderer: ColumnHeaderRendererComponent
}
```

there are few services in the cell renderer component like -

```
    constructor(
    protected readonly permissionService: NgxPermissionsService,
    private readonly translateService: LanguageTranslateService,
  ) {
  }
```

The issue is that first time when cell is renderered services are initialized correctly but if I scroll horizontally some distance and come back the services object are found `undefined`.

framework versions:

```
angular: ^10
ag-grid: ^26.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how ag-grid instantiates the components. However an alternative would be to pass services using `context`, as described in [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-communication/). For example:

Grid component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
      <ag-grid-angular [context]="context" ...other properties>
      </ag-grid-angular>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(translateService: LanguageTranslateService) {
      this.context = { translateService };
  }
}
```

Renderer component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'status-renderer',
  template: `...`
})
export class StatusRendererComponent {
  private _translateService: LanguageTranslateService;

  agInit(params) {
      this._translateService = params.context.translateService;
  }
}
```